# Can the outlook addin track the email read status?

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I am aware that outlook addin can support events that track appointment and emails. Is it possible to implement an addin that can track that an email is currently being read?

Comment: If you're using Outlook native addins then you can use Outlook Object Model API to do so using Mailitem.Unread() property. Here's the documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.unread

Comment: Unfortunately i dont remember any API method to use it directly using office.js/office web addins. Being said that you can EWS from office.js using makeEwsRequestAsync() and call the EWS API call EmailMessage.IsRead Property
which will help you moving forward (incase nothing works for you)! Let me know how it goes.